# Wordpress Hook: Dynamic Tag

Tags: wordpress

I want to set the [Tag of a Wordpress Hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) dynamically with a passed variable:

from

```
add_action('thesis_hook_multimedia_box', 'feat_listings');
```

to

```
add_action($tb_featured_listings_hook, 'feat_listings');
```

This doesn't work, but it sure looks like it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
add_action(get_option('tb_featured_listings_hook'), 'feat_listings');
```